# Custom filter in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I just made a simple custom filter to strip some chars from a string

```
angular.module('myApp.filters').filter('myFilter', function() {
return function(string) {
    string = string.replace('[', '');
    string = string.replace(']', '');
    string = string.replace('","', ', ');
    string = string.replace('"', '');

    return string;
}
});
```

then in the template

```
<td>[[res[0].names | myFilter]]</td>
```

but I keep getting this error:

```
Unknown provider: myFilterFilterProvider <- myFilterFilter
```

I also tried to inject this filter in the controller responsible for that template but no luck. Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you include `myApp.filters` as a dependency in you main app module or another module that is already listed as a dependency?

Comment: yes, I have a file called app.js with this string
angular.module('myApp.filters', []);

Comment: So the `ng-app` in html is `ng-app="myApp.filters"`? Create a demo that reproduces problem

Comment: no in the html I only have a ng-controller, is that the issue? I just tried to add it but still the same.

Comment: Definitely seems you don't have the whole app wired together properly. There can be many modules but they must be included as dependencies under one module that is used as the `ng-app`. Need to see how you configured controller module to help more

Comment: Probably your controller module is not correctly linked to app module and the filter module. If you edit this questions with the modules we can find the hole.

Answer (score 1):

You can build your filter as an angular module and then add that module as a application dependency or just add the filter in the application declaration.

```
// create a module
angular.module('myApp.filters', []).filter('myFilter', function() {
  return function(string) {
    string = string.replace('[', '');
    string = string.replace(']', '');
    string = string.replace('","', ', ');
    string = string.replace('"', '');
    return string;
  }
});
// add the module as a dependency
angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.filters']);
```

or

```
// in the application declaration
angular.module('myApp', []).filter('myFilter', function() {
  return function(string) {
    string = string.replace('[', '');
    string = string.replace(']', '');
    string = string.replace('","', ', ');
    string = string.replace('"', '');
    return string;
}});
```